# Continue to next elif after elif condition is met

Tags: python, if-statement

I am checking for a large number of conditions (hundreds), where each one looks something like this:

```
s = "string"
match = True

if "x" in s:
   var_1 = "something"
elif "y" in s:
   var_2 = "something else"
elif "z" in s:
   var_1 = "something something"
   var_2 = "some thing"
else match = False
```

Problem is that I want to continue to check the rest of the `elif`s even if an `elif` condition is met.

Running everything as `if` instead of `elif` does not work for what I'm trying to do, since I need `else match = False` to trigger if no condition is met.

Is there a work-around?

Comment: I dont think there is even though a trick can be that you initialize `match=false` and later when your any `if` condition is met just make `match= true` and `return` this `match` value

Comment: @shaktimaan I guess that is possible, although that means that I have to add `match = True` for every `if`, which in this case means a few hundred places.

Comment: It has to be something like this only. Although you can reduce the `if-else` conditions. In above code first two `ifs` definitely dont go with last one. either first two will go go or the last one(it seems like this). Since there are hundreds of `ifs` you might have to reduce the no of such conditions, that might reduce the no of assignments,

Comment: Is your `s` constant all the time while your conditions vary?

Comment: @Leb Yes `s` is constant while conditions vary. Although I will change `s` for each pass in another function, but that's unrelated to this.

Comment: do you want to check the elifs even if the original condition is true?

Comment: Just use `if` instead of `elif`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a straightforward answer, just a [proof of concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept).

Use [data driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming) approach. Create a data structure that defines the expected response to individual input characters.

```
DATA = {
    "x": {"var_1": "something"},
    "y": {"var_2": "something else"},
    "z": {"var_1": "something something", "var_2": "some thing"}
}
```

Define a function that builds the required output depending on individual characters in the input string.

```
def process(s):
    d = {}
    for c in s:
        if c in DATA:
            d.update(DATA[c])
    return d
```

Use this function and handle the *no output* situation.

```
d = process("yax")
if len(d) > 0:
    print d
else:
    print "not found"
```

Just for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Let me if I understood correctly:

```
s = "xyz"
match = True

while match == True:
    if "x" in s:
        print("X")
    if "y" in s:
        print("Y")
    if "z" in s:
        print("Z")
    else:
        match = False
    match = False # Prevents from looping forever if all conditions met
>>X
>>Y
>>Z
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Not sure if what would work since match is supposed to be `True` if a condition is met. Adding `match = False ` to the end to prevent loop from stalling would be contrary to that.

Comment: It does stay `True` through each if condition. It's not changed until it passes all 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
s = "string"
letters = "xyz"
intersection = set(s) & set(letters)
if len(intersection) == 0 then:
    match = False
else:
    match = True
    if "x" in s:
       var_1 = "something"
    if "y" in s:
       var_2 = "something else"
    if "z" in s:
       var_1 = "something something"
       var_2 = "some thing"
```